# Localstorage offline JS app : how to set domain to acces local storage from two different html files?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm making a small JS/HTML app in which I like to store preferences in the LocalStorage and access them from two different HTML files

It works if I stay on the same HTML file of course, but when I'm on another HTML page I can't access to the same storage. I saw online it's because I'm not working on the same domain but I've not been able to set a cross domain yet.
I really don't need much place so I would like not to use IDB

main.html :

```
localStorage.setItem("test", myString));
```

other.html : (nothing retrieve)

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem(test));
```

I've tried to use but shows "*Illegal document.domain value*" in the console

```
document.domain="myCustomLocalDomain.xyz"
```

Comment: ew actually i think that you cant if you are not on se the domain

Comment: i think you can do something tricky using iframes, try it

Comment: *"...I've not been able to set a cross domain yet"* What do you mean *"cross domain"?* It doesn't matter there's no workaround hack that exists for such a security exploit,

Comment: "...I've not been able to set a cross domain yet" aka having the same domain on my 2 html files

Comment: The other option is to have 1 giant HTML but it's not that practical

Answer (score 0):

Two different HTML files just simply cannot access the same localStorage object. It simply isn't possible.

Comment: The only way they could is when stored on the same server